# JAXB : Added a Extra tag in XML , the unmarshalling process is not working

Tags: xml, jaxb

This is the XML given

```
<AuthentXML>
<Data>
<header>
<asid>AuthenticationSubjectID</asid>
<teid>B6F997AE-FB4E-11D3-80BD-0050DA5DC7B8</teid>
<replyTo>https://r1.authentify.net/s2s/default.asp</replyTo>
</header>
</Data>
</AuthentXML>
```

**This is my Parser class**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        File file = new File("D:\\Ravi.xml");
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext
                .newInstance(AuthentifyResult.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        AuthentifyResult authentifyResult = (AuthentifyResult) jaxbUnmarshaller
                .unmarshal(file);
        System.out.println(authentifyResult.getData().getHeader().getTeid());
    }
}
```

**This is AuthentifyResult.java**

```
package com;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="AuthentXML")
public class AuthentifyResult { 
    private Data data;

    @XmlElement(name="Data")
    public Data getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

**This is Data.java**

```
package com;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


public class Data { 
    private Header header;
    public Header getHeader() {
        return header;
    }
    public void setHeader(Header header) {
        this.header = header;
    }
}
```

**This is the Header.java file**

```
  package com;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;



public class Header {

private String ASD;
@XmlAttribute
public String getASD() {
    return ASD;
}
public void setASD(String aSD) {
    ASD = aSD;
}
@XmlAttribute
public String getTeid() {
    return teid;
}
public void setTeid(String teid) {
    this.teid = teid;
}
@XmlAttribute
public String getReplyTo() {
    return replyTo;
}
public void setReplyTo(String replyTo) {
    this.replyTo = replyTo;
}
private String teid;
private String replyTo;

}
```

I am getting null as output , i dont know why the bindings are not happening ??

Comment: Could anybody please help me , how to resolve this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<Data>` tag is making JAXB think that `<header>` is contained in an object with the name `Data`. You want to move the contents of `AuthentifyResult` to a new class and then have the `AuthentifyResult` class contain this new class with the element name being `Data`.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="AuthentXML")
public class AuthentifyResult { 
    private Data data;

    @XmlElement(name="Data")
    public Data getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

public class Data { 
    private Header header;
    public Header getHeader() {
        return header;
    }
    public void setHeader(Header header) {
        this.header = header;
    }
}
```

As for the header class, you want to replace the `@XmlAttribute` annotations with `@XmlElement`. The `@XmlAttribute` implies you want your XML to look like

```
<header teid="A Value"></header
```

Whereas, the `@XmlElement` implies you want your XML to look like

```
   <header>
     <teid>A Value</teid>
   </header>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply , but i am getting null as output , i have edietd the question above with your code . please see .

Comment: Fixed for your header class issue. Please let me know if you have any other questions.